# $A\times BC=DEF, K\times GH=DEF$

Tags: puzzle

If $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,K$ are distinct single digit natural numbers and if
$$A\times BC=DEF, K \times GH=DEF$$
where $BC,DEF$ are two and three-digit number. Find these digits. Is the answer unique?

Comment: You did not use H in your equation set.

Comment: There are 372 solutions I think.

Comment: Oh! Yes I changed GF to GH now.

Comment: Why this is not a homework problem?

Comment: Now there are 1470 solutions.

Comment: It may be worth writing a few of them here.

Comment: Any 3 digit number that is the product of a 1 digit number and a 2 digit number is a solution.  Like 8 * 55 = 440

Comment: It is like wording the mathematical statement!

Answer (score 1):

Even I have been trying it out and by brute force I get
$$6 \times 29=174=3\times 58.$$

I wonder if it is unique!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not unique as I get one more possibility:

$$4 \times 39=156=2\times 78$$